# Dumping Array into cells in the Next Empty Row

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I know I can use the following to find the next empty row:

```
nextrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

My question is how do a dump an array (Array(1 to 5)) into the next empty row?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return array to range excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38568263/how-to-return-array-to-range-excel-vba)

Comment: If `nextrow = Range("C2")`, what should the array values occupy? If `C2:C6`, then use `nextrow.Resize(5).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)`. If `C2:G2`, then use `nextrow.Resize(, 5).Value = Arr`.